# Recursive Algorithm Analysis

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

$$T(n) = 2\cdot \sqrt{n} \cdot T(\sqrt{n}) + \Theta (\lg n)$$

I have been trying to solve this question but I could not find anything.

My approach:

$n = 2^k$

$S(k) = T(2^n)$ and $S(k/2) = T(2^{n/2})$

Finally:
$S(k) = 2^{1+k/2} \cdot S(k/2) + c \cdot \lg(k)  $

After that, I tried to build recursion tree but I can not find the sum. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not radical enough. You need $n=a^{2^k}$ and correspondingly $S(k)=T(a^{2^k})$. Note that there were already answers given to the identical question  http://stackoverflow.com/q/22101848/3088138.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting $T(n)=2⋅\sqrt{n}⋅T(\sqrt{n})+Θ(\lg n)$ in terms of

$$n=a^{2^k}\ \text{ and }\ S(k)=T(a^{2^k})⋅a^{-2^k}⋅2^{-k}$$

for some $a>1$ results in the recursion

$$S(k)⋅a^{2^k}⋅2^k=2⋅a^{2^{k-1}}⋅S(k-1)⋅a^{2^{k-1}}⋅2^{k-1}+Θ(2^k⋅\lg a)$$

or after collection

$$S(k)=S(k-1)+a^{-2^k}⋅Θ(\lg a),$$

so that

$$S(k)=S(0)+\sum_{j=1}^k a^{-2^j}⋅Θ(\lg a)$$

and this is bounded by the geometric series, and probably sharper upper bounds exist, the estimates of the Newton-Kantorivich theorem look similar.

So essentially, this $S(k)$ is a constant, and $k=\log_2(\log_a(n))$, rendering

$$T(n)=n⋅\log_a(n)⋅S(\log_2(\log_a(n)))=Θ(n⋅\log_a(n))$$